# Redirect to custom error page from @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using Vaadin 21 and I am trying to handle the error throwed by @RolesAllowed("myRole"), to redirect the user to a custom error page.

I tried to implement a custom AccessDeniedHandler and an AuthentificationEntryPoint, but it doesn't go through them if my user is already connected.

```
 /**
     * Require login to access internal pages and configure login form.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()...
                        .and()
                        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
...
        super.configure(http);

        ...
    }
```

I ended up on a white view with this error :
Could not navigate to 'mypage'

With Vaadin DEBUG activated, I have my list of routes, with the reason of the error "Access Denied".

For more informations, my @Configuration class is implementing VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Any idea how can I redirect my users if they do no have access to a page protected by @RolesAllowed annotation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found out how to do it.
Vaadin has a special way to override the Route Not Found page, which is the target of @RolesAllowed when you do not have the right role (curiously).

The Route Not Found error is also used to handle the error when you try to navigate to a route which does not exist.

So it is basic, I just had to create a class which extends RouteNotFoundError, and do a forward to my AccessDenied.view

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.ErrorParameter;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteNotFoundError;

import project.vaadin.view.AccessDeniedView;


public class CustomNotFoundTarget extends RouteNotFoundError {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3337229943239284836L;

    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(final BeforeEnterEvent event, final ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
        event.forwardTo(AccessDeniedView.class);
        return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    }
}
```

And voilà, I didn't had to modify my HttpSecurity for this. And because my configuration auto redirect to the login view when a user is not logged, I will not encounter this view by mistake for an anonymous user. Perfect in my case.

Comment: This is a bit semi optimal. I was looking for a solution to that issue and ended up at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/exceptions. This however returns 'SC_NOT_FOUND' which is 404. I would prefer to return 403 Forbidden. I would expect that @RolesAllowed would throw AccessDeniedException rather than NotFoundException.

Comment: We have to wait for this to be implemented: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11335

Answer (score 0):

I will share my solution, work around.
I was able to return different page for not found and for not authorised / forbidden.

Spring boot version: 2.7.5

Vaadin version: 23.2.5

First create Annotation.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface RolesPermitted {
    String[] value();
}
```

Add the annotation to the view.

```
@Route("/example")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
@RolesPermitted("ADMIN")
public class ExampleView extends VerticalLayout {

    public ExampleView() {
        add(new H1("Example view"));
    }

}
```

Unfortunately you will need to keep @RolesAllowed or @PermitAll as well.

Next implement BeforeEnterListener.

```
@Component
public class CustomBeforeEnterListener implements BeforeEnterListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        RolesPermitted annotation = beforeEnterEvent.getNavigationTarget().getAnnotation(RolesPermitted.class);

        if (annotation != null) {
            boolean permitted = false;
            String[] roles = annotation.value();
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

            for (String role : roles) {
                String authority = "ROLE_" + role;

                if(authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority))) {
                    permitted = true;
                }
            }

            if (!permitted) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Forbidden");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need UIInitListener implemented.

```
@Component
public class CustomUIInitListener implements UIInitListener {

    private final CustomBeforeEnterListener customBeforeEnterListener;

    public CustomUIInitListener(CustomBeforeEnterListener customBeforeEnterListener) {
        this.customBeforeEnterListener = customBeforeEnterListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void uiInit(UIInitEvent uiInitEvent) {
        uiInitEvent.getUI().addBeforeEnterListener(customBeforeEnterListener);
    }
}
```

Finally you need to implement VaadinServiceInitListener.

```
@Component
public class CustomVaadinServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

    private final CustomUIInitListener customUIInitListener;

    public CustomVaadinServiceInitListener(CustomUIInitListener customUIInitListener) {
        this.customUIInitListener = customUIInitListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent serviceInitEvent) {
        serviceInitEvent.getSource().addUIInitListener(customUIInitListener);
    }
}
```

The implementation of BeforeEnterListener will throw AccessDeniedException in case user hasn't got the required role. In order to catch that you need the following class.

```
@Tag(Tag.DIV)
@AnonymousAllowed
@DefaultErrorHandler
public class AccessDeniedExceptionHandler extends Component implements HasErrorParameter<AccessDeniedException> {
    public AccessDeniedExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event,
                                 ErrorParameter<AccessDeniedException> parameter) {
        getElement().setText("Tried to navigate to a view without correct access rights");
        return HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
    }
}
```

Despite the return statement return HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
You might notice that the response code will be 200. It is an open issue in this version of Vaadin.
https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13421

Credits:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/exceptions

[Why isn't an custom implemented VaadinServiceInitListener is listening in vaadin 13.0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412807/why-isnt-an-custom-implemented-vaadinserviceinitlistener-is-listening-in-vaadin)